# my pagination laravel is weird( i dont know to tell in english my english is suck)

Tags: php, laravel

so I recently learn how to use Laravel for my class project, and heres my problem
when I create pagination the result in my project is <
                                                      .1
                                                      >
like that, the pagination is not styled and the pagination like the picture I upload, I have done everything I could do , I browse the internet too, and the result is null , thanks  [heres the picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBbcY.jpg%60@php()

```
       $no = 1 {{-- buat nomor urut --}}
                )
            @if ($forms->count() > 0)
            @foreach ($forms as $angs)
<tr align="center">
    <td height="32">{{ $no++ }}<div align="center"></div></td>
    <td>{{ $angs->username }}<div align="center"></div></td>
    <td>{{ $angs->nama }}<div align="center"></div></td>
    <td>{{ $angs->nik}}<div align="center"></div></td>
    <td>{{ $angs->status_aktif}}<div align="center"></div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#EEF2F7"><div align="center"><a href="{{ URL('/detailPostAdmin')}}/{{ $angs->id }}">Detail</a> | <a href="">Edit</a> | <a href="">Hapus</a></div></td>

<tr align="center" bgcolor="#DFE6EF">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td> 
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tr>
@endforeach
 {{ $forms->links()}}
```

`
this is my code in blade 
and this is my code in my controller

`
        $forms= login::paginate(3);

```
return view('crud.form.viewMember', compact('forms'));
```

`

Comment: how did you make the pagination? any code you can share?

Comment: this code in my controller  $forms= login::paginate(3);
        ///$forms = login::all();
 
    return view('crud.form.viewMember', compact('forms'));

Comment: and this code in my blade   {{ $forms->links()}}

Comment: im sorry , this is my first time to use stackoverflow

Comment: hi @bramasta, did you use any frontend libraries like bootstrap? or have you customize the [pagination template](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view)? as far as i know, Laravel by default as far as i know assumes you will use bootstrap for styling - see the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/default.blade.php) it [closely resemble bootstrap's pagination](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#pagination). you may want to customise the default pagination to match yours.